# Lenovo T510 taking too long to boot. (Ubuntu Gnome)

Tags: boot, gnome, boot-time

I am quite new to Ubuntu. I ve just installed them to my Lenovo T510 (4384) laptop which also has a freshly installed SSD. The loading time (I 'm talking about the time it spends on the purple screen when it boots with that circle thing in the middle ) is about 90seconds every time i start Ubuntu. I m appending the part of the dmesg log which seems to be problematic.

```
    [    5.682189] input: HDA Intel MID HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input15
[    5.782308] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   50.080429] random: crng init done
[   95.277708] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
```

Thanks in Advance!!
EDIT: My ubuntu version 17.04

Comment: Same problem on HP EliteBook 840 G1. The main problem seems to be crng initialization for my case.

Comment: Hello jonas and sorry for the late response. I did not find a solution so i just switched to 16.04. Boot time is what i expected from an ssd, about 5-8 seconds. I have checked if the issue has been fixed yet in 17.04

Comment: It turned out to be an error in my swap configuration.

Comment: Probably it was the same issue for me too. I recall i didnt set swap size properly. Thanks though!

Answer (score -1):

It could be an error in the swap configuration. I had a swap parition configured in `/etc/fstab` but the partition did not exist. I created a small swapfile instead and the system is booting fine now. The boot will pause at random points when the system is waiting for swap to become available.

Comment: This answers your comment, but not the original question, does it? So please don't post it as an answer.

Comment: Actually it probably answers the original question as well. When formatting ubuntu 17.04 and switching to 16.04 i noticed there was no swap partition in my 17.04 installation.  So I think that was the probable cause for me and Jonas.